# Convert String Date to Time using Moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js and I want to convert my string date into time.

I am getting the date in this format: `Apr 01` and I want the output like `2017-01-01T00:00:00+05:00`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method.

Here a working sample:

```js
console.log(moment('Apr 01', 'MMM DD').format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```